# returning true or false with function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic

Can you please explain why my code was wrong ?
Plus, I did not really understand how works the solution code, please explain.
This is the exercise:
Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative.

```
pos_neg(1, -1, False) → True
pos_neg(-1, 1, False) → True
pos_neg(-4, -5, True) → True
```

## This is my code:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if (a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0):
    return True
  if negative==True:
    if a < 0 and b < 0:
      return True
  return False
```

## This is the solution:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
    return (a < 0 and b < 0)
  else:
    return ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0))
```

Comment: in function use many `print()` to see values in variables in different moments and then run your function with all examples and you will see how your code works and where is mistake. OR learn how to use debugger.

Comment: _ Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative._ - this means you need to check `negative` FIRST before testing the rest,because if its true you need to use different checks..

Comment: See your code execute at : http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1):

In the first if statement, you are immediately returning `True` if one is positive and one is negative, without even checking if `negative` is `True` or not. Instead, you should first check the `negative` argument (and check that both `a` and `b` are negative), then check if one if negative or positive.

Your code would fail if `a` is negative, `b` is positive, and `negative` is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

To explain why your code is not equivalent to the solution, see what happens when you call `pos_neg(-1, 1, True)`. The solution sees that negative is true, then checks if `a < 0 and b < 0` since they are not both less than 0, it returns `False`. Your code first checks if they have different signs, returning true because they do. Only when they have the same sign do you check the negative input.